# The origin of "на авось"

Tags: перевод, этимология, идиомы

The Russian idiom сделать что-то **на авось** is very interesting indeed.

I know that it may be similar to the English idiom **on the off-chance**, which means relying on the remote possibility *(if you can translate на авось into English better, I'll be grateful for your helpful suggestions).*

But what is the origin of the idiom? And what is авось?

Comment: your translation is [accurate](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=on+the+off-chance), as far as the etymology is concerned it's all too obscure [Еще раз о русском авось](http://ec-dejavu.ru/a-2/Avos.html), i wouldn't call it an idiom, because авось here is used in its direct meaning, it's just a verb + adverb

Comment: also the word **авось** is sonically reminiscent of the phrase **а вдруг?** and incidentally (or not) basically carries the same meaning

Answer (score 3):

There are some cases when `на авось` doesn't mean relying on the off-chance. Instead, in about half cases it means carelessly leaving something to the chance when one shouldn't.  Examples from the first 10 in the ruscorpora.ru:

> Светлана была ... поздним ребёнком, родилась случайно, вернее
>   вынужденно: врачи запретили её матери делать очередной тридцать шестой
>   аборт. Они и предыдущие тридцать пятый, и тридцать четвёртый, и
>   двадцать шестой запрещали, но мать надеялась на авось ― и как-то
>   обходилось.

In this case, abortions were dangerous, but the mother still did 35 abortions, and got away with it.  Most probably, the chance of bad outcome was small, maybe 10% or less. It is the serious consequences of bad outcome (possibly death) which justify the usage of `на авось`.

> Направо или налево? Описание маршрута показалось ему таким простым,
>   что записывать поленился, подумал – и так запомнит, чего там. И не
>   запомнил… Он решил действовать на авось и повернул налево.

The chance is 50:50.

> Не надейтесь на авось
>   15 апреля в Новгородской области начинается всеобщая диспансеризация взрослого населения.

Again, the chance of good outcome is higher than 50%, since most people are not sick. But for some people, the medical check-up may save their life.

> Ночевка рядом с немецкой границей в Польше (в Польше на порядок
>   дешевле). Нам ночь в мотеле на 5 обошлась около 1000 р. Отель только
>   во Франкфурте бронировала заранее, и то не оплачивала а просто по
>   электронке. В Дюссельдорф приехали на "авось". Отель системы Холлидей
>   Инн Экспресс, такой перевалочный пункт для транзитных пассажиров, но
>   очень приличный и недорогой. Места всегда есть по факту. Так же по
>   пути туда и обратно в Польше ничего не бронировали, приезжали и
>   заселялись сразу.

It seems the chance of good outcome here is close to 100%.

> Прозвонщик ― это профессия, ― пояснил Родион, ― мелкий воришка,
>   который действует безо всякого плана, полагаясь на авось.

Again, the chance of "good" outcome (good from the thief's point of view, of course) should be much higher than 50%, otherwise he wouldn't be able to "work" like this.

Translations in real texts do not use off-chance. Some examples from reverso.net:

- ну, надеемся на авось - well, I guess we roll the dice
- она прослушалась на авось - she had auditioned on a whim
- положиться на авось и убить человека - to go with your gut and kill a person
- не люблю надеяться на авось - I don't like leaving too much on chance
- все живут одним днём в надежде на авось - all live one day a time
  trusting to luck